# What exactly is an NSTreeController's "arrangedObjects"?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstreecontroller

I'm trying to bind an NSTreeController's "arrangedObjects" to a custom view's "managedContent" (so that it can show a custom outline, for instance).  In the setter...

```
- (void)setManagedContent:(NSArray *)newManagedContentArray {
    //code goes here
}
```

nothing ends up working since newManagedContentArray ("arrangedObjects") apparently isn't an NSArray (and therefore I can't addObject: etc. etc.) Instead it's showing up as an NSControllerTreeProxy. My question is, what exactly is "arrangedObjects" supposed to be? Am I supposed to bind to it? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arrangedObjects` isn't supposed to be an array for `NSTreeController`. It states this quite clearly in the documentation. What you do get is the proxy object you are seeing, which you can use the `childNodes` and `descendantNodeAtIndexPath:` method on to get your tree structure.

Comment: Oh whoops. I looked at the documentation and I feel... "stupid" now. Thanks.

Comment: Don't - you should see the answer I was typing before _I_ checked the docs!